# C# convert HTML markup with svg code to PDF

Tags: c#, javascript, html, pdf, svg

I am working on ASP .NET 3.5 framework Web Form application. I have a HTML page with a kendo UI chart and other HTML tags.

I want to convert this page to pdf. I tried pechkin by posting back my html string to code behind. But it displays the svg data as normal text and renders the HTML properly. But the svg is not displayed as image.

I also have code that converts the svg xml to bitmap image. But how to add this image to the PDF instead of the svg xml (something like replacing the svg xml with  tag)

Comment: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf has many example chart libraries formatted to pdf from svg as vector information. You can test Kendo yourself and if you have an issue, post on css-to-pdf on github and we will investigate.

Comment: OK, we added Kendo charts. Took only a minute. http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.kendo

Comment: Thanks @KevinBrown, but the plugin calls a service and our requirement does not allow this. If we can know what the service does behind the scenes, we can implement the same.

Comment: It uses RenderX behind the scenes through REST in a .NET environment. Their hosted environment is free but to runin your own is commercial.

Comment: @KevinBrown cloudformatter was perfect for what I needed to do. Thank you so much!!